# Saving the value of a selected radio button to a dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to save the value of the radio button that is selected and store the value into a dict to send back to the server as a `JSON`. For all other `input types` I refer to their `data-name` and `val()` to get both keys and values.

I couldn't do this for radio button values so instead I get the value of the radio button and store it manually. The problem is that it not only updates the latest value for that particular record displayed it overrides all previous values with this new value, which I don't want.

This is the JQuery:

```
 radioVal='school';

 $('.metwhere').on('change', function() {
     radioVal = $('input[name=met' + index + ']:checked').val();
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.send', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var contactDataToSend = [];
    $('.contact').each(function () {
        var data = {};
        $(this).find(':input[data-name]').each(function () {
            data[$(this).data('name')] = $(this).val();

        });
        data['metAt']=radioVal;
        contactDataToSend.push(data);
    });
```

And the html:

```
<input type="radio" class="metwhere" name="met' + index + '" value="tradeshow"   id="tradeshow' + index + '"><label for="" class="control-label text-muted">  <b>&thinsp;Tradeshow</b></label><br>
<input type="radio" class="metwhere" name="met' + index + '" value="flight" id="flight'   +     index + '"><label for="" class="control-label text-muted"><b>&thinsp;Flight</b></label>    <br>
<input type="radio" class="metwhere" name="met' + index + '" value="train" id="train' +     index + '"><label for="" class="control-label text-muted"><b>&thinsp;Train</b>    </label>    <br>
<input type="radio" class="metwhere" name="met' + index + '" value="hotel" id="hotel' +    index + '"><label for="" class="control-label text-muted"><b>&thinsp;Hotel</b></label><br>
```

How can I amend this to only use `radioVal` to not override previous records: Or is there a method in which `data-` attribute can be used to capture only the selected radio button value?

Comment: can you share the html ?

Comment: In your `$('.metwhere').on('change', function() {` what's the value of index?

Comment: Index counts the number of times a button is clicked which dynamically creates these html elements

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste this to your developer tools console:

```
var data = {};
data["a1"] = 1;
data["b1"] = 2;
data;
data["c1"]=3;
data;

var data2 = {};
data2["a"] = 1;
data2["b"] = 2;
data2;
data2["a"]=3;
data2;
```

The only way that the last one overrides the previous values is if they use the same key. So your problem seems to be that all values are using the same key. Double check your inputs, their ids, their data-names, etc to make sure they're all unique. In your

```
$('.contact').each(function () {
```

before

```
data['metAt']=radioVal;
```

do

```
console.log(data)
```

to see what the values are.

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked but my index values are incrementing each time a new `div` element is added: `index = $('#contacts div').length + 1;`

Comment: @user94628 Add the `console.log(data)` before and after `data['metAt']=radioVal;` and see what it shows.

Comment: Shows the radioVal data being overwritten, but all my keys are unique

Comment: Can you post the result of your first and 2nd console.log here?

Comment: Having problems viewing console.log as both FF and Chrome not displaying